# How to make a filetype behave exactly like C++?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, indent

I want the filetype `.my_cpp` and `.my_cc` to behave exactly like C++ files in Vim. I have the following set:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.my_cc set syntax=cpp
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.my_cpp set syntax=cpp
```

Although the syntax highlighting works, the indentation doesn't seem to be working like C++ at all. How can I fix this? I assume it would have something to do with `indentexpr` but I don't know enough about Vim to make it work. Doing `set indentexpr?` in an actual `.cc` file gives me `indentexpr=`, so I guess it's not set to anything?

I would appreciate any help on the matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.my_cpp setlocal filetype=cpp
```

Read `:help :setfiletype` and decide if it applies to your or not.

---

Even better would be to create `~/.vim/ftdetect/my_cpp.vim` with

```
autcmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.my_cpp setlocal filetype=cpp
```

You won't need to set `syntax`.

If you do instead `:setlocal filetype=my_cpp` than you can create `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/my_cpp.vim` and `~/.vim/after/syntax/my_cpp.vim`.

You can make them behave like `cpp` filetypes with

- `:runtime! ftplugin/cpp.vim ftplugin/cpp_*.vim ftplugin/cpp/*.vim`
- `:runtime! syntax/cpp.vim`

respectively.

As @filbranden points out:

> For indentation, you might need an `indent/my_cpp.vim` as well. If you define your own syntax file, you might want to set `b:current_syntax` appropriately (even if all you do is source the original cpp syntax files.)

Note that if you just `setlocal filetype=cpp` everything is taken care of for you. The reason *not* to would be if you needed the `cpp` filetype *and* some (usually small) extensions.

Comment: For indentation, you might need an `indent/my_cpp.vim` as well. If you define your own syntax file, you might want to set `b:current_syntax` appropriately (even if all you do is source the original cpp syntax files.)

Comment: Thank you Ben and @filbranden. I'm not writing an extension or anything, just want these files to be detected as cpp and behave exactly like them, mainly talking about indentation and syntax highlighting here. Hopefully `autcmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.my_cpp setlocal filetype=cpp` in `~/.vim/ftdetect/my_cpp.vim` will be enough. Is the `~/.vim/indent/my_cpp.vim` necessary if I am not writing extensions/plugins?

Comment: If you're setting the filetype to `cpp` (which is definitely the easiest) then the `ftdetect` file with the one line is all you need!

Comment: @filbranden Additionally, can I group many `ftdetect` `.vim` files together? Something like `{my_cpp,my_cc}.vim`? Or must I create individual `ftdetect` files? I have many filetypes that I want to be detected as C++

Comment: You can put many autocmd lines in one file @herophant

Comment: @herophant The file name doesn't really matter (well, as long as it's in the right directory and it has a `.vim` extension)... Usually you want it to be called something unique (so it doesn't conflict with other existing ones.) You can add several autocmd's in the same ftdetect file, yes.